# R- Scatter plot with confident intervals

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this in R

```
method    est   lower   upper
A         5.7    5.2     5.8
B         6      5.5     6.4
C         5.9    5.6     6.1
```

The second column is the estimate of a parameter. The first column is the method used to obtain those estimates. 3rd and 4th columns are 95% lower and upper bounds of the estimates. The true value is 6.

I want to make a plot with 3 points spaced evenly vertically. Each point corresponds to an estimate. Thus the vertical axis is for the method. The horizontal axis is the magnitude of the estimate. Across each point there is a short horizontal line which represent the 95% confident interval. And finally there is a long vertical line representing the true value.

Can anyone point me to which package or function that can help me with this task?

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is really for helping you debug when you get stuck. To do that, there has to be an attempt, even if it's not working.

Comment: Also helpful to show what you're expecting as output, even if it's a photo of a sketch you made on paper that shows what you want the plot to look like when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [docs for `geom_errorbarh()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_errorbarh.html) and for [`geom_vline()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_abline.html) in the `ggplot2` package.

Maybe you are aiming for something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data_frame(method = LETTERS[1:3],
                 est = c(5.7, 6, 5.9),
                 lower = c(5.2, 5.5, 5.6),
                 upper = c(5.8, 6.4, 6.1))

ggplot(df, aes(x = est, y = method)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 5.75), colour = "red")
```

[image]